# Hover Div System

Tags: jquery, html, css

Say I have a div with a link in it. When I hover over it I want another div to fade in above it with some content and then fade away on mouse over.

Example found here:
http://bit.ly/c59sT4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something re-usable using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [the fading functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/), like this:

```
$(".container").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hover").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".hover").fadeOut();
});
```

For example, here's the demo markup, though the `<div>` elements can contain anything:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hover">
        Content Here
    </div>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Then via CSS you just position that inside `<div>` absolutely and the give it the same size, like this:

```
.container, .hover { width: 100px; height: 300px; background: white; }
.hover { position: absolute; display: none; }
```

[You can give it a try here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/UrR2N/).

Comment: +1 for the CSS part and after seeing your demo i realized I was not doing what he is looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

html:

```
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
  <div id="divtofadein">some content here</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
 $("#divtofadein").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
 })
   .hide();

 $("#link").click(function(){
  $("#divtofadein").fadeIn();
 });
});
```

css:

```
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
}

#link {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

#divtofadein {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
background: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Congrats on your first answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery and its [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) functions, in conjunction with [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

For that you'll want to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) in particular the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event.  Once you get to grips with it you'll find it trivial to do tasks like this that work cross browser.